# Optimizing nbody algorithm in F#

Tags: algorithm, optimization, f#

How could be optimized this code further:

```
let rec nCollect func = function
        | [] -> []
        | x::xs -> let firstAndNext body (firstBody, ys) = 
                        let newFirst, z = func firstBody body
                        newFirst, z::ys
                   let y, ys = List.foldBack firstAndNext xs (x, [])
                   y::(nCollect func ys)
```

This code is part of nbody simulation program. It is getting each body and is applying a func function between it and each next. Results are used for next iterations. I optimized it slightly with lists. The problem is that the input bodies are under 10 in count, but nCollect is called millions times. For example if I use tail recursion in nCollect the result is worse.

Comment: Other than tail recursion what have you tried? Do you have a test that shows the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the answer to 90% of all micro-optimization problems in every language is always the same: use arrays, loops, and mutation.

So, I would use arrays, loops, and mutation, rather than `List.foldBack`.

Comment: List.foldBack is a loop in its nature, but the problem is with the intermediate data created from loop body (firstBody). If it is smart enough to reuse memory locations for the intermediate storage then it will be fine. But will the compiler made such a magic?

Comment: @The_Ghost: If it were easy to tell if a method were pure this would be possible, however it is extremely difficult to do in F#. One of the  problems with easy access to mutability.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick comments

`List.Fold` should beat `List.FoldBack`.  Looking at the code here - https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs you can see that FoldBack will allocate a temporary array, which could be slow, whilst fold can quickly iterate through the list.

You could also try inlining `firstAndNext`

Manually unrolling the loop could help as well

Comment: Inlinening didn't helped. Strangely but foldBack in my case is running faster.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a better algorithm like Ewald summation or Fast Multipole Method (FMM).
2. Replace lists and recursive functions with arrays and `for` loops.
3. For small problems, replace loops with custom code generation.